# Locate the code that throws an error in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a rather large piece of code in a file that uses D3 to build a chart. Sometimes I get error messages in Chrome that help me to find the line where the error happens by showing the file and line number, but sometimes I get messages like this:

[image: Error message]

As you can see, there is not much information about where to search for this erroneous code, because I have a lot of code that works with text elements as well as setting attributes like `x`shown here.

How do you work with errors like this? How would you go searching the line having just this? Is there a better way than just going through all code that works with `text` element and setting `x` attribute?

Comment: @PatrickEvans that only helps him know which part of the D3 code throws the error, not which one of his many functions passed NaN to the d3 `attr` function

Comment: Yeah, @explunit, it doesn't seem to help me in finding the error in my code. I think it would be nice to have some way to debug errors in D3-powered code. May be there are 3rd party libs to make it easier?